# function call on ok click button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Following is my code. The modal popup appears. When i click `ok` the user should redirect to an actionmethod. How can I do that. Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        debugger;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            debugger;
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "Alert!",
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('ok');
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href` like this

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    title: "Alert!",
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            window.location.href = " put your url "
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either `window.location.href` or `window.location.replace` in your ok button response function.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    title: "Alert!",
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
           window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
           return false;
        }
    }
});
```